# QFT in in the asymptotic region

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, renormalization, s-matrix-theory, asymptotics

Let $\phi(x)$ be a scalar field operator. It often postulate in text books that  in the asymptotic region we have
$$\lim_{x_0\to-\infty} \phi(x)=\sqrt Z \phi_{in}(x)$$
where $Z$ is a constant.

The justification is that there is self interaction in the asymptotic region.

My question is why not postulate  $\lim_{x_0\to-\infty} \phi(x)= \phi_{in}(x)$? what $\sqrt Z \phi_{in}(x)$ gives us that  $ \phi_{in}(x)$ does not gives?

Answer (score 1):

The *Yang-Feldman* equations describe the interpolating field:
$$
\phi(x)=\phi_{in}(x)-\int \mathrm{d}^4y \Delta_R(x-y)j(y),\\
\phi(x)=\phi_{out}(x)-\int \mathrm{d}^4y \Delta_A(x-y)j(y),
$$
where $\Delta_R$ ($\Delta_A$) is the retarded (advanced) propagator. It happens that you can't switch off self-interactions as one usually does with other sources $j(x)$, so the integrals don't vanish in the asymptotic limits $t\to\pm\infty$. Thus, the renormalization constant $Z$ is necessary, and defined by
$$
\lim_{x_0\to-\infty}\langle b|\phi(x)|a\rangle=\sqrt{Z}\langle b|\phi_{in}(x)|a\rangle,\\
\lim_{x_0\to-\infty}\langle b|\phi(x)|a\rangle=\sqrt{Z}\langle b|\phi_{out}(x)|a\rangle.
$$
It has an intuitive meaning: $Z$ is the probability for the interpolating field to create a single-particle state when acting on the vacuum:
$$
|\langle 1|\phi(x)|0\rangle|^2 = Z |\langle 1|\phi_{in}(x)|0\rangle|^2.
$$

I recommend Greiner's Field Quantization (chapter 9) for further reading.

Comment: My question is  what $\sqrt Z \phi_{in}(x)$ gives us that  $ \phi_{in}(x)$ does not gives?

Comment: Because the integrals in the Yang-Feldman equations do not vanish with self-interactions, so $Z=1$ can only describe a free theory. The $Z$ allows for change in the number of particles.

Comment: In what manner $Z$ allows for change in the number of particles?

Comment: A field equation is in general written as $\mathcal{D}\phi(x)=j(x)$, where $\mathcal{D}$ is a differential operator. The formal way to solve this is by using Green's function technique, which leads to the Yang-Feldman equations I wrote. If the source is limited ($j(x)=0$ for $|x_0|>T$), it is obvious that your definition applies $\lim_{t\to\mp\infty}\langle a|\phi|b\rangle = \langle a|\phi_{in/out}|b\rangle$ is valid, but this is not the case for fields that self-interact.  Then, you need to relax the equality condition and go for simple proportionality.

Comment: why the constant of proportionality solves the problem?